# Linearization of constraints with square root

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I am trying to solve an optimization programming model involving a non-linear constraint with a square root. It follows (in a simplified form): $X_i\ge\sqrt{A_i/B_i}$ where $X_i,A_i,B_i$ are positive variables.

Can you please give me some indications to solve?

Comment: Hi and welcome to OR.SE. Is there any index associated with A and B? Do you want to linearize the constraint?

Comment: You tagged the question "mixed-integer-programming". Are any of the variables integer-valued?

Comment: @OguzToragay Yes, both variable A and B are associated to index i, as for X. All the variables are integer.

Comment: Please provide more information on the objective and any other constraints.  Viewed in isolation, this constraint could be handled, by squaring both sides, with Geometric Programming, although that is not linearization.Depending on the rest of the model, mnaybe it makes sense to handle it as a nonlinear constraint $X_i^2B_i \ge A_i$?